# Nintegration of coupled function

Tags: numerical-integration, polynomials, series-expansion

I have function `Q[x,t]=p1[x]*u1[t]+p3[x]*u3[t]+p3[x]*u3[t]`

where,

```
p1[x]= -Cos[4.73 x] +   Cosh[4.73 x] -   0.9825 (-Sin[4.73 x] +  Sinh[4.73 x]);
p2[x]= -Cos[7.85 x] +   Cosh[7.85 x] -   1.00077 (-Sin[7.85 x] + Sinh[7.85 x]);
p3[x]= -Cos[10.99 x] +   Cosh[10.99 x] -   0.99996 (-Sin[10.99 x] + Sinh[10.99 x]);
```

I need to evaluate `NIntegrate[(Q[x,t])^3*(p1[x]+p2[x]*p3[x])^3,{x,0,1}]`

the final result should be in terms of unknown functions u1[t], u2[t] and u3[t].

*Note:*
using NIntegrate instead of Integrate is to save time because this is repeated many many time in different form. some how i need to do this `u[t]*NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]` for all the terms

Comment: `NIntegrate[]` can only gives numeric calculations and results.

Comment: @Feyre There are terms like `f[x] u[t]`; I think the OP wants to automatically do `u[t] NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]` for all such terms.

Comment: @corey979 yes this is what i want, i just edit it to be more clear.

Comment: Notwithstanding the possible error in the construction of `Q[x,t]`, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42916/how-to-use-nintegrate-when-there-are-symbolic-constant-coefficients) might contain a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought of a slightly different approach using the general method proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42916/how-to-use-nintegrate-when-there-are-symbolic-constant-coefficients). I'm not great with Mathematica shortcuts so I'm sure that the code can be simplified, but start by splitting the expression into lists.

I should mentioned that I assumed `Q[x,t]` should be:

```
qxt = p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t] + p3[x]*u3[t]
```

though it can easily be changed to the form originally written. The total integrand is

```
exp = qxt^3*(p1[x] + p2[x]+p3[x])^3;
expandexp = Expand@exp;
```

Listing the terms:

```
terms = List @@@ List @@ expandexp;
```

Split the list based on function type:

```
elemtest[k_] := MemberQ[k, x, Infinity]
ints = SplitBy[#, elemtest] & /@ terms;
```

Function definitions:

```
p1num[x_]:=-Cos[4.73 x]+Cosh[4.73 x]-0.9825 (-Sin[4.73 x]+Sinh[4.73 x])
p2num[x_]:=-Cos[7.85 x]+Cosh[7.85 x]-1.00077 (-Sin[7.85 x]+Sinh[7.85 x])
p3num[x_]:=-Cos[10.99 x]+Cosh[10.99 x]-0.99996 (-Sin[10.99 x]+Sinh[10.99 x])
```

Now solving the integral:

```
NIntegrate[
  Table[Times @@ 
       Flatten[ints[[i, ;; (Length[ints[[i]]] - 1)]], 1], {i, 1, 
       Length@ints}] /. p1 -> p1num /. p2 -> p2num /. p3 -> p3num, {x,
    0, 1}].Table[Times @@ Last@ints[[i]], {i, 1, Length@ints}]
```

Yielding:

```
(*8.43022 u1[t]^3 + 31.985 u1[t]^2 u2[t] + 44.6085 u1[t] u2[t]^2 + 
 21.3727 u2[t]^3 + 17.1899 u1[t]^2 u3[t] + 
 56.9567 u1[t] u2[t] u3[t] + 48.9372 u2[t]^2 u3[t] + 
 27.9564 u1[t] u3[t]^2 + 45.872 u2[t] u3[t]^2 + 15.9643 u3[t]^3*)
```

---

Verifying the solution:

Checking for `u1[t]==1`, `u2[t]==2`, and `u3[t]==3` directly:

```
NIntegrate[(p1[x] + p2[x] + p3[x])^3 (p1[x] 1 + p2[x] 2 + p3[x] 3)^3 /. 
    p1 -> p1num /. p2 -> p2num /. p3 -> p3num, {x, 0, 1}]
(*2910.71*)
```

and using the extraction method:

```
NIntegrate[
   Table[Times @@ 
        Flatten[ints[[i, ;; (Length[ints[[i]]] - 1)]], 1], {i, 1, 
        Length@ints}] /. p1 -> p1num /. p2 -> p2num /. 
    p3 -> p3num, {x, 0, 1}].Table[
   Times @@ Last@ints[[i]], {i, 1, Length@ints}] /. {u1[t] -> 1, 
  u2[t] -> 2, u3[t] -> 3}
(*2910.71*)
```

Comment: There is difference in your answer and the first answer ?

first answer
8.43022 u1[t]^3 + 31.985 u1[t]^2 u2[t] + 44.6085 u1[t] u2[t]^2 + 
 21.3727 u2[t]^3 + 17.1899 u1[t]^2 u3[t] + 
 56.9567 u1[t] u2[t] u3[t] + 48.9372 u2[t]^2 u3[t] + 
 27.9564 u1[t] u3[t]^2 + 45.872 u2[t] u3[t]^2 + 15.9643 u3[t]^3

Comment: I had `(p1[x] + p2[x]+p3[x])^3` accidentally as `(p1[x] + p2[x] p3[x])^3`. I made the change and now the answers are matching up.

Comment: what about if i want to increase the number of p and u lets say up to 5 what are things gonna change ? is there a way to make it automatic depending on jj= number of p and u?

Comment: Have you tried modifying it to see? It should be as straightforward as changing the function definitions at the top and for each of the $p_i$ functions.

Comment: what is the difference between extraction method and solving the NIntegral ?

Comment: By explicitly setting $u_i = i$, `NIntegrate` can directly solve the problem. The extraction method, originally asked for in the question, doesn't assume a form of $u_i$ during the integration.

Answer (score 4):

What about using `CoefficientList` on the integrand in order to obtain the coefficients?

```
n = 3;
us = Array[u, n];
ps = {
   -Cos[4.73 x] + Cosh[4.73 x] - 0.9825 (-Sin[4.73 x] + Sinh[4.73 x])
   , -Cos[7.85 x] + Cosh[7.85 x] - 
    1.00077 (-Sin[7.85 x] + Sinh[7.85 x])
   , -Cos[10.99 x] + Cosh[10.99 x] - 
    0.99996 (-Sin[10.99 x] + Sinh[10.99 x])
   };
Q = us.ps;
exp = Q^3*Total[ps]^3;
cl = CoefficientList[exp, us];
integrals = NIntegrate[cl, {x, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
integrals
```

[image]

It does not take very long and you can recreate the expression by considering the ordering of `CoefficientList` (see documentation)

[image]

**EDIT**

You can reconstruct the expression as a linear combination of the powers taken into consideration in `CoefficientList` as follows

```
temp = Table[
   us[[1]]^i*us[[2]]^j*us[[3]]^k, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}];
res = Total[integrals*temp, Infinity]
```

[image]

In case you want to check, use random numbers for the `us`

```
ureplace = Table[u[i] -> RandomReal[], {i, 3}];
NIntegrate[exp /. ureplace, {x, 0, 1}]
res /. ureplace
```

> 10.2957
>
> 10.2957

Comment: can i have them in form of u1[t], u2[t] and u3[t] rather than u[1], [u2], u[3]?

Comment: You can do that by just replacing the symbols, use `/.` and what you need.

Comment: i tried to use this /. u[n_] -> Subscript[u, n][t] but its not working right to convert it to u1[t], u2[t] and u3[t]

Comment: `res /. {u[1] -> u1[t], u[2] -> u2[t], u[3] -> u3[t]}`

Comment: just to make sure i understand the code you are evaluating this 
exp = Q^3*Total[ps]^3;
right ?

Comment: Yes and I think you should be able to understand the code and look up the functions I used.

Comment: i have one last doubt, in case i want to change the n to 5, ill make n=5 then add five function in ps. what about temp = Table[
   us[[1]]^i*us[[2]]^j*us[[3]]^k, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}]; how i can modified it to fit n=5 ?